# Get availability of formers for a sitting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, drop-down-menu

I have two forms; the first is the form `formers` with two fields (name, firstname).

[image]

I also have the form `trainings` with two fields (date_sitting, fk_former).

[image]

My problem, if I want to add the other sitting today (07/07/2019), I would like to see only the formers who have no training today.

Here, I retrieve a former who has a sitting today.

[image]

Do you think it's possible to get only the `formers` who have no of sitting for now?

Edit: 10/07/2019

**Controller Training**

```
public function index()
    {
        $trainings = Training::oldest()->paginate(5);

        $formersNoTrainingToday = Training::whereDate('date_sitting', "!=", Carbon::today())
           ->orWhere('date_sitting', null)->get();

        return view('admin.trainings.index', compact('trainings', 'formersNoTrainingToday'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page',1) -1)*5);

    }
```

And

```
public function create()            
    {

        $formers = Former::all();
        return view('admin.trainings.create', compact('formers','trainings'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to see only the formers who have no training today.

Sure - you can determine your correct list of candidates to show by using the following query:

```
$formersNoTrainingToday = Training::whereDate('date_sitting', "!=", Carbon::today())
           ->orWhere('date_sitting', null)->get();
```

This should work... but it assumes a few things within your code / db.  If this fails, consider a few options to **replace** the `whereDate` section above:

Using where:

```
->where('date_sitting', '!=', \Carbon::today()->toDateString())
```

Using formatted date if that column on the DB is a different format than Carbon:

```
->whereDate('date_sitting', "!=", Carbon::now()->format('m/d/Y'))
```

If you're not using Carbon for some reason, you can try the raw query route for today:

```
->whereDate('date_sitting', "!=", DB::raw('CURDATE()'))
```

Bottom line, here are a number of ways to get *close* to this.  But you may need to tweak this on your own to suit your needs.  You may need to take Timezone or some hours of difference into account, so you may need to add a range or buffer.  But the above should get you close if not all the way there.

HTH

Comment: Thank yet for your help. I don't know `Carbon`... I would like to stay on my function store() in fact. Because I yet am newbie in laravel. I don't understand how I can get the id of formers available. I do not know the syntax to do

Comment: To get the ids of the formers (and names if used in the Training model), use the code above but instead of `get()`, use `->pluck('name', 'id');`.  This will give you a list of no training today ready for dropdown use.  But, you can't use this in the dropdown if it is only on the `store()` method - that would just be to verify on those who haven't trained today *after submitting the new training for storage*.  So maybe a little refactoring on your code if you want to prevent showing formers who already have training (send this via `show()` method).

Comment: Thank you for your explicate. I am trying to understand but it's very intricate for me, especially with my level. It's impossible to get the "formers" availables on a dropdownlist with the method store() ???

In fact, my goal is to retrieve the "formers" only on the page create.blade to to simplify the add of a "training". 

Create a button "show" is not feasible for this type exercice. Sorry :-(

Comment: I think we are talking about the same thing.  I think you want to trim the list of 'formers' in the dropdown to not show those who already have training for that day.  To do that, you need to send the reduced list (using the filter code by date above) to the create.blade.  All I was saying was that you need to filter the list of 'formers' in whatever method *sends* the code to create.blade.  `store()` won't work since that comes *after* the create.blade stuff is sent.  So, whatever method you use to send to create.blade (`create()`?) would work - doesn't have to be `show()` :)

Comment: AllRight, I have understand for the method "store()" now, thank you, it possible to use the function index() for example?

Comment: Sure, you can use whatever you wish to send the name/id list to the dropdown.  The key is that you filter with the date to trim list in whatever method you choose.  Totally up to you how you structure it, but convention is typically to use the `create()` method to send this type of list for new elements about to be created, `edit()` to show the edit screen with the dropdown, and `show()` if just showing what is already there.

Comment: I am trying to filter now via la date... I don't understand at all, the synthax...My line here seems incorrect   `$listformers = Training::where('date_sitting', $request->pluck('name', 'firstname','id');`  
                                                                                                                                 Here is my function create() for now

 `$formers = Former::all();
        $listformers = Training::where('date_sitting', $request->pluck('name', 'firstname','id');
        return view('admin.trainings.create', compact('formers','trainings'));
    } `

Comment: Hmm, this might be a place to review the docs and study queries and get(),pluck(),first(), etc.  The syntax you have above isn't going to work.  The pluck() needs to come at the end.  So, you are looking at something like: `Training::whereDate('date_sitting', "!=", Carbon::today())
           ->orWhere('date_sitting', null)->pluck('name', 'id');`  It is not part of the date filter, but for the entire collection, and thus at the end of the query.  Too big to go into here, but definitely review a few tutorials on this :)

Comment: No problem, thank yet for your help... I am looking several tutoriels...

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to do it without Carbon? Because I have no idea there

Comment: You can - look at the very last example using Raw.  But, I strongly urge you to learn Carbon - it's built into Laravel and the basics are very quick to learn.  It makes working with dates a little easier.

Comment: I wonder how you did, I edited my first post, I do not have an error message but I do not get the available formers.